# A few specific Rails questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a few specific questions. I have tried googling these but I get a lot of extremely general info. I've also looked at tutorials but generally they are so long I can't find my specific Question.

Thanks!

- what is the difference between :test, :development and :assets? Rails 3.2.1 groups :development, :test but in the "Rails 3 Tutorial" videos i'm watching he breaks them out separately.
- how many tests do you usually write? It seems you could write 5... or infinite. Where is the sweet spot?
- which javascript folder do I use? I notice there is a public folder and then theres a folder i can place stuff into under assets called 'javascript' and 'images'. Do i need to use those assets folders or is it ok to put 'js' and 'img' (my preferred naming convention) inside of /public
- how do i compile scripts/stylesheets? I noticed uglifier is in there, is there some command that compresses css and js and combines them into one file? (one css, one js)
- how do i run commands whenever i run rails console? I know how to put `gem 'hirb'` in Gemfile, but I want to run `extend Hirb::Console` every time rails console is run for that project so I don't have to type it, and i can generate my tables nicely

Comment: You should ask these as separate questions on SO, not as one big question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with what JacobM said above in a comment, but perhaps I can sum these up for you.

1. This question is slightly vague. Are you referring to rails environments or are you referring to the `Gemfile`? I am going to assume you mean the `Gemfile`. In that case, the

   group :assets do
     gem 'sprockets'
     gem 'assets-ftw'
   end

is a way of telling bundler when to include those gems. You don't need `:testing` gems in your `:development` profile, and vice versa, etc. Its good organization.

1. This question doesn't have a hard or fast answer. It really depends on the code you are writing. It is advised to test completely. Make sure your unit tests cover all aspects of your model and using integration testing to ensure user actions are completing successfully up and down the stack.
2. I would advise against renaming the folders inside the `/assets` directory, but rails may let you do that. The files found in the assets folder are their to be compressed when the rails app is put into production. The `/public/javascripts` folder is where `.js` files used to reside before Rails `3.1`
3. To compile assets you run the rake command `rake assets:precompile`
4. I'm not sure.

For more complete answers. I would split these up into longer questions, but search SO more completely, as I think most of these have been asked before.

Comment: Thank you for that. My last clarification I'm wondering is, what actually are dev, assets, and testing in the rails environment? Like what is the difference between them. Development makes sense, its things not used in production, but what about assets and testing? Thanks again

Comment: Its just stating that those gems deal with the assets directory, precompiling, moving, converting from coffeescript->js or sass->css, etc.

While testing is obviously an environment just for testing the code in the rest of the application.

Comment: thanks, assets makes lots of sense. As for 'testing' that seems kind of vague. What if I'm using rspec-rails? Thanks again for your clarifications, I'm not quite new to ruby but this is my first rails project.

Comment: I'm new-ish to Rails too but the whole testing thing has just starting clicking for me - when you run RSpec tests, they make use of gems that you don't need for development or production, so specifying them as :test saves the load time when they're not needed. In the Rails Tutorial, the `'factory_girl_rails'` gem is a good example - ALL it does is generate fake users and posts for use during the tests. You only ever touch the test part of things via RSpec, so it can feel a little abstract.